# Large number of -1 posts

Tags: discussion, voting

Seems lately there are an excessive number of -1 votes on unanswered & answered questions, majority of which are unwarranted.
Just 'fixed' probably 10 found in the latest 50.
What's going on?

Edit: here's 6 from yesterday (retrieving history from phone is a pita, there were more..

- [Keyup Event Not Work in Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180091/keyup-event-not-work-in-chrome)
- [Ubuntu seemingly not detecting GPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180116/ubuntu-seemingly-not-detecting-gpu)
- [How do you boot into Ubuntu from USB on Chrome OS without SeaBIOS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180109/how-do-you-boot-into-ubuntu-from-usb-on-chrome-os-without-seabios)
- [Trouble creating a default desktop for new users 18.4.03](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180123/trouble-creating-a-default-desktop-for-new-users-18-4-03)
- [What files can the Xfce4 desktop environment run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180088/what-files-can-the-xfce4-desktop-environment-run)
- [Problem with touch screen in Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180133/problem-with-touch-screen-in-xubuntu)

Point is there where at least a dozen in 50 most recent, more like someone is just down voting without any consideration.

Comment: Could you give some examples? What makes votes “unwarranted” in your eyes? If they’re your own votes just undo them, if not – well, they are other people’s *votes*…

Comment: Another reason for apparently random up/down votes could be people aiming for the *Vox Populi* badge: *Use the maximum 40 votes in a day*.

Comment: Doesn't it seem a bit pointless downvoting users with only 1 rep anyway? What is the point?

Comment: Probably just someone being malicious or as mentioned the Vox Populi badge. As mentioned there were at least 10 (probably more) -1's in the 50 most recent, none with a comment, most unwarranted. In most cases this was done to new users which made me feel bad, so upvoted them...

Comment: (Slightly unrelated to this post, it's a reply to the comment by @Graham above) "*Doesn't it seem a bit pointless downvoting users with only 1 rep anyway? What is the point?*" - We downvote posts, *not* people. The goal is *not* to reduce rep of a user, it's a moderation task.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid we can not really investigate that issue as moderators, because individual users' votes are anonymous and there is no way to know who voted on a specific post.

Probably the pattern will stop on its own soon or might even have stopped already. Otherwise, if it's clear that someone is actually trying to cause damage, it might have to be escalated to the SE Community Managers or Developers team, but that should only be done in emergencies.

Let's keep observing for now and see what happens. Sorry that we can't give a more satisfying response at this time.